# Show dates in a custom format

Tags: date, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.0.10 and I'm trying to use this date format `dd/mm/yyyy` everywhere in my application, instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I know from the documentation that I can use `ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'it_IT');` setting in my `bootstrap.php` file to do most of the dirty work, but still I am obtaining dates in `dd/mm/yy` format, which is not good for me. Setting it to `fr_FR` returns the right format, but obviously I'm missing all the translations and it is just wrong anyway :)

How can I override the default behavior of the italian locale, to obtain 4 digits years?

Comment: I've found the solution while looking more deeply in the documentation. In the AppController it is necessary to add `use Cake\I18n\Time;` and `Time::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
\Cake\I18n\Time::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

See [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string), you could put this line in the `beforeRender` callback of your `AppController`:

```
public function beforeRender (\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    \Cake\I18n\Time::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    return parent::beforeRender () ;
}
```