# CakePHP 3 display the wrong date format

Tags: cakephp, date-format

This date format 2016-04-21 is stored in the database, but it's display like 21.04.2014. on my website. This is very frustrating. 
Solution echo $object->field->format('Y-m-d'); is not good for me.
I would like to define settings that this is not happening anymore.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: This is a version of CakePHP 3.1

Comment: what date format do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show dates in a custom format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635700/show-dates-in-a-custom-format)

Comment: Also **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676227/cakephp-3-2-change-default-date-format**

Comment: I want 2016-04-21 date format like saved in datebase.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
$date="2016-04-21";
$require_date_format = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));//will out put 21.04.2016
```

Comment: -1 The question is about CakePHP, its date/time objects, and a global, configurable solution. What you are showing here is the cumbersome variant of the `format()` call in the question.